# CSS style won't apply to div

Tags: html, css

It's the first time I've used divs in CSS.  I know there are other threads out there asking similar questions - I've read these, and they didn't help.

Here's my CSS:

```
.global {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color:#2C3539;
    border-color:#000000;
    border-width:1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

And here's the html:

```
 <div id="global">
    <h1>Global Element</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Global 1</li>
        <li>Global 2</li>
        <li>Global 3</li>
        <li>Global 4</li>
        <li>Global 5</li>
    </ul>            
</div>
```

In the html, the div is nested within body, but I tried nesting the div in CSS within body, that didn't work.  I know the style sheet is linked to the html file properly, because when I applied the above css to body it worked.  Am I missing something extremely simple? Thanks

Comment: `.global` should be `#global` -- you are selecting an `id`, not a `class`. Alternatively, you could also change `<div id="global">` to `<div class="global">`.. either way, that's your problem.

Comment: Or change `<div id="global">` into `<div class="global">`.

Comment: Hey folks, go easy on down-voting someone new to CSS

Comment: Sometimes the down voting sucks. New to CSS, should be given a thumbs up for trying to learn something new! @ Naomi Endicott push to learn more.

Comment: Thank you Ted and Tez! and Josh for your clear answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While others have pointed out that your CSS and HTML did not match because of classes being used in your CSS, and IDs being used in your HTML, it is important to know when to use each.

IDs are used in CSS/HTML when there is only one instance. IDs are essentially like *private* CSS--one that will have changes affect it and only it.

IDs have their place in design, and a well thought out structure should take advantage of IDs. Consider IDs to be *safe*. If you change the style of an ID, it is only going to affect that particular area, so you don't need to worry about changes having effects on various other parts of your site.

However, if you want this--which many do, as it reduces the amount of editing that you need to do--then you use classes. Classes are, essentially, like *public* CSS, and as a result, changes to a CSS class will affect any HTML that uses said class. Classes, as you can probably guess, are generally more widely used because of this *reusability*. You can create basic classes and apply them all over your site.

A basic example of this in action would be the following:

```
#logo {
  width: 150px;
  color: #000000;
}

.white {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Here, your `#logo` is an ID. This is something that is a static element at the top of your site, so it isn't going to be reused. The `.white` is a class, which applies a white background to any element. This is something that could be reused.

**note that these are extremely basic examples

So, you could have something like:

```
<div id="logo" class="white">MyLogo</div>
```

Which would apply your white class to your logo id, making your logo have a white background.

It is important to think about your structure in this way when you are designing. It is worth taking a bit of time to figure out if, and how, you can reuse your code.

Answer (score 6):

If you use an **id** in your HTML code, you need to use **#** in the css code.

```
<div id="global"></div>
```

```
#global { }
```

If you use a **class** in your HTML code, you need to use **.** in the css code.

```
<div class="global"></div>
```

```
.global { }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Your selector is wrong,

```
<div class="global"></div>
```

uses

```
.global {
}
```

There's a difference in using .select and #select

```
<div id"global"></div>
```

uses

```
#global {

}
```